# Getting an error while running npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm getting this kind of error.

```
C:\Users\Sulagna(mana)\Desktop\Angular Application\quickstart-master>npm install
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...Shrinkwrap":false,"di'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sulagna(mana)\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-24T18_43_22_701Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Sulagna(mana)\Desktop\Angular Application\quickstart-master>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Delete **node_modules** folder
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install`

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It says that the npm package minimatch@0.3.0 has a security vulnerability and therefore asking you to update it to version 3.0.2

You will need to update the minimatch version in your package.json.